# jQuery stop listening event while animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-animate

I'm writing some code with jQuery.

There are some div with class 'icon' in my html, and I hide a div with class 'hide' beside each 'icon'.

I want that when user's mouse get in to 'icon', the corresponding 'hide' will make animate.

But I found that if I quickly move the mouse in and out the 'icon'. The animate will excute twice. And it make my web's visual effects very terrible.

So I want stop the event while animate excuting, I read a lot of artical and document then try, but still can't solve it.

This is my code.

```
$(".icon").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $(this).closest(".slideli").find(".hide").show("slide", {direction: 'right'}).animate({duration: 500, easing: "swing", queue: false});
});
$(".icon").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).closest(".slideli").find(".hide").hide("slide", {direction: 'right'}).animate({duration: 500, easing: "swing", queue: false});
});
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: ^ Possibly a jsfiddle?

Comment: try using `.stop()` before `.animate()`.

Comment: Looks like confusing everyone (at least me...) if you want to stop the current animation or avoid event to be fired. You should really provide a jsFiddle or code snippet replicating your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery's [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to prevent new animations from being added to the queue all the time. You can either use `.stop(true,true)` or `.stop(true,false)` depending on your need:

- if you only want to clear the animation queue and let it animate to completion by itself, use `.stop(true,false)`
- if you want to clear the animation queue **and** force the animation to jump to its end state immediately, use `.stop(true,true)`

Here's your improved code:

```
$(".icon").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $(this)
    .closest(".slideli")
    .find(".hide")
    .stop(true,true)
    .show("slide", {direction: 'right'})
    .animate({duration: 500, easing: "swing", queue: false});
});
$(".icon").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this)
    .closest(".slideli")
    .find(".hide")
    .stop(true,true)
    .hide("slide", {direction: 'right'})
    .animate({duration: 500, easing: "swing", queue: false});
});
```

You may also use [`.finish()`](http://api.jquery.com/finish), but since your animation is rather simple (you are not chaining consecutive animations in any instances), `.stop()` can do the same job, too.

p/s: A shameless plug to a quick article on handling jQuery animations I published some time ago: [How to .stop() writing bad jQuery animations](https://medium.com/coding-design/how-to-stop-writing-bad-jquery-animations-f1481782dc4e)

Comment: I undestood it differently regarding OP saying: `So I want stop the event while animate excuting`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid event to be fired on animated element(s), you should use pseudo selector `:animated` as following: `:not(:animated)`

```
$(".icon").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $(this).closest(".slideli").find(".hide").filter(":not(:animated)").show("slide", {direction: 'right'}).animate({duration: 500, easing: "swing", queue: false});
});
$(".icon").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).closest(".slideli").find(".hide").filter(":not(:animated)").hide("slide", {direction: 'right'}).animate({duration: 500, easing: "swing", queue: false});
});
```